# Is it possible to pass a MXBean as a message in Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I want to send a MXBean as a message from one endpoint to another.
Does the JMX message format already included in Apache Camel support this?

My project involves me getting an MXBean of a JVM on a local machine. I will be using the CompilationMXBean, MemoryMXBean etc.... [found in java.lang.management.*] to get the JVM information.

Also i am using an XML file to create routes.
And then creating the components/endpoints in Java.(
using the dispatch/acquire functions).

Or is there a way to create custom message parsing?
Am fairly new to apache camel.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JMX component in Camel is really intended to pass around JMX notifications. The MXBeans are not passable as messages themselves, but if I understand what you're trying to do, there's a couple of ways you can pass data samplings as Camel messages:

1. Pass an encapsulated reference to an endpoint which interprets the reference into one or more JMX calls to the referenced MBeanServer/MXBean to acquire the specified values. A reference can be generically encoded as a JMXServiceURL, an ObjectName and a list of attribute names or operation name/parameter pairs.
2. Alternatively, you could create a new MXBean, installed on your target JVMs, that periodically samples all the required local MXBean data, aggregates it and emits it as a JMX notification. The emitted notifications can then be handled by the standard Camel JMX component.

Comment: Your second point was very clear. But i did not fully understand what you meant in point 1.
I have an alternative solution of mapping every information I will be using from the Mxbean and just pass the map as a message.

Comment: That's pretty much what I meant. You are representing an MXBean invocation in the map that you are passing as a message. Is it working for you ?

Comment: Alright. Havent tried it yet. I am in the middle of making some more changes to one of the modules i had. Need to add some more functionality before i can go ahead and process information for JNA message passing. I will definitely update on what i did once i get it done. Thanks

Comment: Yes it is working for me. I did run into a casting issue if i passed a Map<String, CustomClass>, i am not sure how to tackle that. Ended up passing it as Map<String, String>.

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to take a look at [jolokia](http://www.jolokia.org/) (http://www.jolokia.org/) - its a great project to make it easier to integrate with JMX in local and remote JVMs and use a simpler API that can be REST and JSON based.

It supports bulk operations, so you dont have chatty calls etc.

We are using Jolokia in our [hawt.io](http://hawt.io/) project (http://hawt.io/) to gather data from a web based console from remote JVMs that run Camel, ActiveMQ, ServiceMix, and the likes.

Comment: The issue with that would be that i am restricted to a Camel only.

Comment: I don't grok what you mean by "a Camel only"?. You mean 1 JVM only? hawt.io communicates with a JVM (usually the one that serves up the web app) but we're adding Fuse Fabric integration so you can view an entire cluster of processes with Camel's in each one.

Comment: No i mean, this project is not a personal one but a company project. So i cannot divert from the technology i have to use. Have to make do with the custom base classes created under camel.